# What is $\int_\gamma \frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}?$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, parametrization, greens-theorem

> Let $\gamma$ be the oriented piecewise $\mathcal C^1$-arc consisting of the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$, followed by the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$. What is $$\int_\gamma \frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}?$$

I am trying to parametrize this arc so that I can integrate the $1$-form but I am having trouble doing this. Any hints?

Comment: How do you use green theorem for unclosed loop?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Right. Actually I just need to integrate the $1$-form given.

Comment: Hint: what is (formally) $$ d\,\arctan\frac{y}{x}$$ and what is the geometrical meaning of $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ for $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant?

Comment: We have $$d \arctan \frac{y}{x}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}.$$ But does this help me set up the integral?

Comment: @AlJebr: how many turns does your curve around the origin? I would say half a turn, leading to an integral equal to $\pi$. Can you see why?

Comment: But are we looking at a curve, or are we looking at two straight line segments?

Comment: Two straight line segments sharing an endpoint *are* a curve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Green's Theorem to relate the integral over the union of two line segments to an integral over a half-circle.

Two reasons: 1. It is easy to compute the integral over the upper half unit circle, and 2. The result is the same as computing the integral over the union of two line segments.

Use Green's Theorem on the *closed* curve consisting of the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$, followed by the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$, then the upper half circle centered at the origin from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ - caveat: the curve above is oriented clockwise, but the result is 0.

Comment: But we don't have a half circle. We have two straight line segments. Why would we look at a circle?